# Passing variables to ng Animate

Tags: angularjs

How do I achieve variable animations?

Right now what I'm doing is getting my element and accessing its scope:

```
myApp.animation('.my-anim', function () {
    return {
      addClass: function(element, className, done) {
        var target = angular.element(element).scope().target;
        TweenMax.to( element, 1, { x : target.x, y: target.y,  onComplete : done } );
      }
});
```

However, I am not sure if this is the 'angular' way. I have searched the docs and they don't seem to document this usecase.